# MySQL Deadlock on stored procedure when inserting

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So for some reason, I just got this error message: `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, but I'm not quite sure why since I've never gotten this before, and it used to work fine.

**Stored procedure**

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddTestResultRequirement`(varTestResultId INT, RequirementNameId INT)
BEGIN
    declare reqId INT;
    declare linkId INT;
    set linkId = -1;
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM testcaserequirement where nameId = RequirementNameId) THEN
        insert into testcaserequirement(id, nameId) values (NULL, RequirementNameId);
        set reqId = last_insert_id();
    
    ELSE
        set reqId = GetRequirementNameId(RequirementNameId);
        
    END IF;
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(select * from testresultrequirementlink where requirementId = reqId and testresultId = varTestResultId) THEN
        insert into testresultrequirementlink(id, requirementId, testresultId) values(NULL, reqId, varTestResultId);
        set linkId = last_insert_id();
    
    else
        set linkId = GetRequirementTestResultLinkId(varTestResultId, reqId);
    
    end if;
    
    select linkId;
END
```

**Function**

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `GetRequirementTestResultLinkId`(varTestResultId INT, RequirementId INT) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT id from testresultrequirementlink where testresultid = varTestResultId and requirementId = RequirementId LIMIT 1);
END
```

Anyone who can see where this deadlock would appear?
I do know that deadlock means that `a deadlock is when two transactions are trying to lock two locks at opposite orders`, but I still can't figure out why I got it.

Comment: is anything else running on the database?

Comment: Well we have some machines which triggers a 'scraper' job when they are done, so I guess multiple jobs could be 'scraped' on the same time, and use the same stored procedures on the almost same time

Comment: To get more information about possible deadlock use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command.